# Javascript show next possible delivery date

Tags: javascript

I have a website, where the client can see the delivery date.
[image]

Here is the code

```
function getProductRecordHTML(Product, index, quantity, ProductType, blok)
{
    var manufacturer = "", article_show = "", name = "";
                
    var time_to_exe = Product.time_to_exe;

    var displayDate;
    if(time_to_exe == 6)
    {
        const date = new Date();
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + parseInt(time_to_exe));
        displayDate = date.toLocaleDateString();
    }
    if (displayDate) {
  time_to_exe = displayDate;
      
    } else {
      time_to_exe = time_to_exe + "d";
    }
```

For now, `time_to_exe` gives the delivery time in days
This code calculates the next delivery date just by adding these 6 days to the current date.

My main goal is to get the period from Monday to Wednesday at 12 pm, if it's true then `time_to_exe` shows the date of next Monday (for example 23/08/2021), but if it's false (for example it's period from Wednesday after 12 pm till Sunday 11:59 pm) then `time_to_exe` show Monday date 1-week after (for example 30/08/2021).

I hope explained clearly.
Already many thanks to the user @Christopher for helping before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to work with dates much easier is to use a library like [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) (which I have been using for years), or maybe even better a newer library like [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/), since moment.js is going into maintenance mode.
Let's see how you would achieve your date calculation using moment.js:

```js
var orderDateTime = moment('08/18/2021 8:15 am');
// Get Sunday (first day) of this week and add 3 days (to get to Wednesday) and set the time to 11:59am
var cutOffDate = moment().startOf('week').add(3,'days').set({'hour': 11, 'minute': 59, 'second': 59});
// Initialize delivery date from order date
var deliveryDate = orderDateTime.clone();
if (orderDateTime.isSameOrBefore(cutOffDate)) {
    deliveryDate = deliveryDate.add(1,'week').startOf('week').add(1,'day'); // Monday next week
} else {
    deliveryDate = deliveryDate.add(2,'week').startOf('week').add(1,'day'); // Monday the week after next
}
alert("Delivery Date is "+deliveryDate.format("MM/DD/YYYY"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

That's all you need for your calculation.
You can also find a fiddle of the code above at https://jsfiddle.net/yLpf3vxj/

Comment: @Karl-Hernry Martinson Thanks for the help and advice, I really appreciate it. The last question - if I choose `format("D MMMM")`, is it possible to set `MMMM` to local language?

Comment: @EdijsMaļinovskis - Yes, you can find that information in the section about localization (il8n).

Answer (score 1):

The Javascript [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object includes a `getDay()` method that returns a numerical value for the day of the week. From this it's possible to work out the previous Monday's date, and then add 7 or 14 depending on the original date.

This function takes a JavaScript `Date` object and returns the relevant Monday as another `Date`.

Note that `setDate()` will update month and year as appropriate if the date being set is outside the current month.

```
        function getMonday(orderDate) {
            orderDate = orderDate || new Date();
            if (!(orderDate instanceof Date)) {
                throw "Invalid date";
            }
            // Get the date last Monday
            let lastMonday = new Date(orderDate);
            lastMonday.setDate(lastMonday.getDate()-lastMonday.getDay()+1);
            // If order date is before Wednesday noon, deliver next Monday. Add 7 to last Monday date
            if (orderDate.getDay()<3 || ((orderDate.getDay() === 3) && orderDate.getHours()<12)) {
                lastMonday.setDate(lastMonday.getDate()+7);
            } else {
                // Otherwise. add 14 to last Monday date.
                lastMonday.setDate(lastMonday.getDate()+14);
            }
            return lastMonday;

        }
```

input:

```
    let testDates = [
      new Date(),
      new Date(2021,7,18,11),
      new Date(2021,7,18,13), 
      new Date(2021,9,1,11), 
      'bad date'
    ];
```

Output:

```
Wed Aug 18 2021 10:14:41 GMT+1200 (New Zealand Standard Time), Mon Aug 23 2021 10:14:41 GMT+1200 (New Zealand Standard Time)
Wed Aug 18 2021 11:00:00 GMT+1200 (New Zealand Standard Time), Mon Aug 23 2021 11:00:00 GMT+1200 (New Zealand Standard Time)
Wed Aug 18 2021 13:00:00 GMT+1200 (New Zealand Standard Time), Mon Aug 30 2021 13:00:00 GMT+1200 (New Zealand Standard Time)
Fri Oct 01 2021 11:00:00 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time), Mon Oct 11 2021 11:00:00 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time)
Invalid Date
```

Demo:https://jsfiddle.net/dzsf34ga/

Comment: Thanks for the help and advice, I really appreciate it

Comment: @EdijsMaļinovskis Don't forget to upvote or accept an answer if it has helped you.